# Is non static members inside public static class thread safe?

Tags: asp.net, class, static, thread-safety, public

Can you check this function for me. Is it thread safe or not to be used. I am trying to understand how exactly public static classes are working.

This function will be used to get userId of visitor from database by username. So many concurrent call may happen. Also would this be the best performance way and sql injection secure.

**ASP.net 4.0 - C# - MSSQL 2008 R2 - IIS 7.5**

```
using System;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

public static class csGetUserId
{
    public static string srCommandText = "select UserId from tblUsersProfile where userName=@userName";

    public static string ReturnUserId (string srUserName)
    {
        string srUserId = "0";

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(DbConnection.srConnectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(srCommandText, connection);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", srUserName);
                SqlDataReader dsReader = null;
                connection.Open();
                dsReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (dsReader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (dsReader.Read())
                    {
                        srUserId=dsReader["UserId"].ToString();
                    }
                }
                else
                {

                }
            }
            catch
            {
                srUserId="-1";
            }
        }
        return srUserId;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the database supports multiple connections and that you change srCommandText to be readonly then this method is thread safe.
Making srCommandText read-only will also make it safe against SQL injections.

Comment: yes database is microsoft sql server 2008 r2. So the variable srUserId  will be unique for every session right ? It will be created and used whenever a call happened. So lets say 100 concurrent call happened. In that case how would this function work ? 1 complete then goes other one or 100 call gets executed at the same time ?

Comment: srUserId is a method variable. A different instance will be created for each method call. This method will be executed multiple times at parallel. Note that you should not "swallow" the exception. You should at least log the error message.

Comment: but when 100 concurrent call happened would they get executed at the same time or start first finish start second ?

Comment: thanks for valuable comments. I think from now on i should create classes like this. Until now i was writing in each page same code for doing same things :) And also making public static classes would increase the performance right ?

Comment: I don't think that you will see any measurable change in performance.